# If my Canadian visa expired in June, can I travel in April?

Tags: visas

If my Canadian visa expired in June, can I travel in April? I am from Trinidad & Tobago.

Comment: Yes............

Comment: As you can see from the answer, the years are relevant. Please edit your question.

Comment: It's tempting to edit the tense in this question as tense mistakes are very common among non native speakers of English, but I'm not going to because it might actually be correct as written

Answer (score 7):

If the visa is expired, you cannot travel with it. If it is not expired, you can travel with it. It's as simple as that. If it expires tomorrow, it is still valid today. If it expired yesterday, you cannot travel today.

So:

- If your visa expires June 2018, you **can** travel April 2018.
- If your visa expired June 2017, you **cannot** travel April 2018

If your visa is no longer valid, you'll need to look into extension options or make a fresh application for a new visa.

Answer (score 2):

If it already expired in June 2017, no.  You would have to get your visa extended, or renewed.